# Logical Equivalence of Statements

Tags: python

In Python, generally speaking, is it true that nested `if` statements are logically equivalent to `if` statements with `and` in them? So would:

```
lista = ["1", "2"]
if "1" in lista and not "3" in lista:
     print("True")
```

be the same as:

```
lista = ["1", "2"]
if "1" in lista:
   if not "3" in lista:
       print("True")
```

Or does Python treat them differently?

Comment: first one is direct checking of 2 conditions, in 2nd one is it checking both condition but also lead to a state where when first condition is true and second is not then what happen

Comment: Just to say `not "3" in lista` can be written `"3" not in lista` which in my eyes flows better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those are equivalent.

However, you need to be careful if there is an `else` branch – many bugs have been caused by the mistaken transformation between

```
if a and b:
    do something
else:
    do a different thing
```

and

```
if a:
    if b:
        do something
else:
    do a different thing
```

Comment: I've become a firm believe in no plain `if` statements, only perhaps to exit early, e.g. `if arg == something: return something_else` or perhaps `if something: continue`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, yes it's equivalent. But bear in mind that nested if statements could also contain more.

For example:

```
if a:
    if b:
        do something
    do another thing
```

is not the same as:

```
if a and b:
    do something
    do another thing
```